# magick++ , no matching function for call to?

Tags: c++, magick++

```
using namespace std ;
using namespace Magick;
list < Drawable> text_draw_list;
text_draw_list.push_back( DrawablePointSize( 8 ) );
text_draw_list.push_back( DrawableFont( "Bookman-Demi" ) );
text_draw_list.push_back( DrawableStrokeColor( Color( "white" ) ) );
text_draw_list.push_back( DrawableFillColor( Color( 1, 1, 1 ) ) );
text_draw_list.push_back( DrawableText( 0, 10, "c" ) );
my_image.draw(text_draw_list );
```

Im trying to use magick++ API but im keep having this strange error (I'm using eclipse c/c++ as IDE ):

```
no matching function for call to ‘Magick::Image::draw(std::list<Magick::Drawable>&)
```

on the console:

```
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++/Image.h:845:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::list<Magick::Drawable>’ to ‘const Magick::Drawable&’
/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++/Image.h:848:10: note: void Magick::Image::draw(const std::vector<Magick::Drawable>&)
 void draw(const std::vector<Magick::Drawable> &drawable_);
      ^

/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++/Image.h:848:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::list<Magick::Drawable>’ to ‘const std::vector<Magick::Drawable>&’
```

after searching :

in Magick++ api 7 it is not possible to use std::list with magick::image::draw() , std ::vector instead should be used . 
all guides and PDFs available for Api 6 NOT Api 7 .

Comment: So there is no `draw` for `std::list`, just for `std::vector`? How would that affect your design?

Comment: So what's the question? Magick++ switch from `std::list` to `std::vector` for drawing context. It'll take some time until all the documentation is updated to reflect changes. See [Porting to ImageMagick 7](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php) guide for additional info.